# div's breaks when i animate using jquery animate() method

Tags: html

Hi i have used four div's in this page. if i click one div then it will shows its content by shrinking other divs into 10%.
[click here](http://devt.webwings.in/716864/ECG_ANIM/)

My problem is, when i click about div then technology and protection divs breaks down to the page and come back.
i want to animate without breaking of that div.

here is my code following for about div click,

```
    //ABOUT CLICK STARTS HERE
  $("#about").click(function()
  {
        $('#about-con').css({'display': 'block', 'width': '45%', 'right': '30%'});
        $('#technology-con').css({'display': 'none', 'width': '', 'right': ''});
        $('#protection-con').css({'display': 'none', 'width': '', 'right': ''});
        $('#distribution-con').css({'display': 'none', 'width': '', 'right': ''});

        $("#distribution").animate({'width': '10%', 'float': 'left', 'margin-left': '45%'}, 800);
        $('#technology').animate({'width': '10%', 'float': 'left','margin-left': ''}, 800);
        $('#protection').animate({'width': '10%', 'float': 'left','margin-left': '-17px'}, 800);
        $("#about").css({'width': '25%','float': 'left','margin-left': ''},800);

    }); //END OF ABOUT CLICK
```

**css:**

```
#about{
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 5;
    }
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: okay wait i will create.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kaargo/szg733zr/2/ here is the fiddle